# Non-automated website stability testing services

Tags: testing, web, cross-browser

Have done a lot of searching and still not found a site that offers real-user testing across the range of browsers including Ipad 1,2,3 in a non-virtual or automated way.

We recently had a site that crashed Ipad 1 (the client's Ipad of course) but could not be replicated in any of the online services so we now want to send our completed websites out and get back a report that it works across IE 7-10, Chrome and all Ipad generations etc.

Does anyone know of such a service. As said, it must be on actual devices not virtualised one.

Thanks in advance.